# How to create a filter function with api call and context?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-context, react-native-flatlist

I have a react native web app. And I try to create a filter function for animals. The data that will return via the filter function is generated by an api call. And I am using a context for injecting the api call. And then in the component I try to call the filter function from the context in the component.

And I am using flatlist for showing the animals on the cards. But for example if I try to filter the list with Wolf. Nothing happens.

So this is the api call:

```
export const fetchAnimalData = async (text) => {
    const token = await retrieveToken();
    try {
        if (token) {
            const response = await fetch(`${API_URL}/api/animals/?name=${text}`, {
                method: "GET",
                headers: {
                    Authorization: `Token ${token}`,
                    Accept: "application/json",
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                },
            });
            return await response.json();
        } else {
            throw new Error(token);
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("There was a problem with the fetch operation:", error);
        throw error;
    }
};
```

And this is the context:

```
import React, { createContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { fetchAnimalData } from "./animal/animal.service";
export const SearchAnimalContext = createContext();

export const SearchAnimalContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [searchAnimal, setSearchAnimal] = useState([]);
    const [results, setResults] = useState([]);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const [error, setError] = useState(null);
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

    const handleSearch = (text) => {
        setSearchAnimal(text);
    };

    const filteredData = searchAnimal.filter((item) =>
        item.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchAnimal.toLowerCase())
    );

    const performSearch = async (text) => {
        setLoading(true);
        setError(null);

        fetchAnimalData(text)
            .then((response2) => {
                setResults(response2);
                setIsLoading(false);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                setLoading(false);
                setError(err);
            });
    };
    return (
        <SearchAnimalContext.Provider
            value={{
                filteredData,
                searchAnimal,
                setSearchAnimal,
                handleSearch,
                performSearch,
                results,
                loading,
                error,
            }}>
            {children}
        </SearchAnimalContext.Provider>
    );
};
```

And I inject the function performSearch from the context in this component:

```
export const SubCategoryScreen = ({ route, navigation }) => {
    const [subCatgoryList, setSubCategoryList] = useState([]);
    const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    const [searchAnimal, setSearchAnimal] = useState("");
    const [input, setInput] = useState("");
    const { performSearch } = useContext(SearchAnimalContext);
    const [searchTimer, setSearchTimer] = useState(null);
    const [results, setResults] = useState([]);
    const { toggle, showAccordion } = useContext(ToggleContext);
    const [toggleIcon, setToggleIcon] = useState(true);
    

    const handleClickIcon = () => {
        setToggleIcon(!toggleIcon);
    };

    const filteredData = subCatgoryList.filter((item) =>
        item.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchAnimal.toLowerCase())
    );
    return (
        <SafeArea>
            {isLoading && (
                <LoadingContainer>
                    <ActivityIndicator animating={true} color={MD2Colors.green200} />
                </LoadingContainer>
            )}
            <Searchbar
                placeholder="Searchie"
                onChangeText={(text) => {
                    if (searchTimer) {
                        clearTimeout(searchTimer);
                    }
                    if (text.length === 0) {
                        console.log(text, "TEXT");
                        return null;
                    }
                    setInput(text);
                    setSearchTimer(setTimeout(performSearch(text), 1000));
                }}
                value={input}
            />
            

            {results.length > 0 ? (
                <CategoryList
                    data={results}
                    renderItem={({ item }) => {                     
                        return (
                            <>
                                <Spacer>
                                    <SubCategoryInfoCard subcategories={item} />
                                </Spacer>                               
                            </>
                        );
                    }}
                    keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
                />
            ) : (
                <CategoryList
                    data={filteredData}
                    renderItem={({ item }) => {
                        return (
                            <>
                                <TouchableOpacity
                                    onPress={() => navigation.navigate("groepen", { subcategories: item.id })}
                                    disabled={
                                        isLoading ||
                                        (!item.hasOwnProperty("animals") && !item.hasOwnProperty("subcategories"))
                                    }>
                                    <Spacer>
                                        <SubCategoryInfoCard subcategories={item} />
                                    </Spacer>
                                </TouchableOpacity>                             
                            </>
                        );
                    }}
                    keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
                />
            )}
        </SafeArea>
    );
};
```

But in the list nothing is filtered. But if I put a breakpoint on this line in the context component: `setResults(response2);` in devtools

Then It reruns the correct result. For example I search for Wolf

```
response2: Array(1)
0: {id: 8, name: 'Wolf', sort: 'Canis lupus', uis: false, cites: 'nvt', …}
length: 1
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

If I put the api call method directly in the `SubCategoryScreen` component with this in it:

```
response.json().then((response2) => {
setResults(response2);
```

Then it works

But if I do this in the SubCategoryScreen :

```
if (text.length === 0) {
    console.log(text, "TEXT");
    return null;
}
```

Then I only see the TEXT message. But not the result of text

Question: how to filter a specific animal from the flatlist?

Comment: Hey, why are you using `useContext` hook, is there any specific reason? because you can just skip it by using `useQuery` and passing props properly to the components.
can you provide a `Expo Snack` i think you can achieve it with really less code.

Comment: `searchAnimal.filter` implies that searchAnimal is an array, which conflicts with `searchAnimal.toLowerCase()` and `setSearchAnimal(text)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `SubCategoryScreen` you use:

```
const [results, setResults] = useState([]);
```

Which is never updated. `performSearch` will update the `results` in the context, but not in the `results` state in the `SubCategoryScreen` component

You probably want to use the following instead:

```
const { performSearch, results } = useContext(SearchAnimalContext);
```

Similarly you might also want to pull `loading`/`error` from the context.